# Trouble with loading cells from UITableView

Tags: uitableview, view, split, autosize

I am developing an application with a list of objects in a UITableView. The problem occurs when I am in landscape mode where I use a split view (TableView on the left, View on the right). When I select an object it loads the middle of the view instead of the top. I want the view to appear from the top when I select a new object from the tableview.

It seems like it has something to do with autosizing. It works when I remove autosizing (the l---l on the top) on a textview in my View, but then my windows get messed up. Anyone know the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` of that view and set the `view.frame.origin.y = 10`. It must solve the problem